# Unpacking list of lists generated by a zip into one list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, zip, multiple-columns

I am again manipulating dataframes.
Here I concatenate multiple dataframe using row as common reference.
Then I want to reorder the columns by "pairing" the first one columns of each df together, and so on. All for the sake of data readability

Here is my code:

```
df_list=[df_1,df_2,df_3]   
return_df=pd.concat(df_list,axis=1, join='outer')
dfcolumns_list=[df_1.columns,df_2.columns,df_3.columns]
print (return_df.columns)
print(dfcolumns_list)
list_columns=np.array(list(zip(*dfcolumns_list))).reshape(1,-1)[0]
print (list_columns)
list_columns=np.array([x for x in zip(*dfcolumns_list)]).reshape(1,-1)[0]
print (list_columns)
return_df=return_df[list_columns]
```

My question is related to:

```
list_columns=np.array(list(zip(*dfcolumns_list))).reshape(1,-1)[0]
```

or alternatively

```
list_columns=np.array([x for x in zip(*dfcolumns_list)]).reshape(1,-1)[0]
```

It takes the list of indexes, unpacks it in the zip, takes the first element of each column index, outputs it as a tuple/sublist contained in a list, transforms it into an array ,then reshapes it to get rid of the sublists which would cause the

```
 return_df=return_df[list_columns]
```

to break. At last, the call to index 0 `[0]` allows it to retrieve the final list into the np.array  (which I need to reshape).

My question is: is there nothing less ugly than that? I like `zip` and similar functions, but I hate to have no simple mean/trick to unpack the generated tuples/sublist for reordering purposes.

(It also came to my mind while redacting that I could maybe do the df differently, so I would also give points to that, but my main question is still how to do what I am doing more elegantly/with more Pythonic syntax.
The `[0]` in the end is the dirtiest of all...

Comment: That's not valid python code. The `[df_1.columns print(return_db.columns)` is a syntax error.

Comment: Corrected the badly done correction/anonymization of my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just zip all column lists and then flatten the list of lists

```
list_columns = [ col for cols in zip( *dfcolumns_list ) for col in cols ]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the chaining of for cols in zip() for col in cols? I understand "for cols in zip" but don't get the double recursivity there... Would you mind developping, please?

Comment: In list comprehension you may have nested for loops. The order of these for loops is based on the order in which they appear in "traditional" nested for loops. So, the first for loop: ``for cols in zip( *dfcolumns_list)`` iterates of each list in list in `zip( *dfcolumns_list)`. The second for loop, ``for col in cols`` iterates over each such list cols. ``col`` are items in ``cols`` and are added to the result.

Comment: Allright, I get it! Thanks a lot. Do you know if it is quicker than the use of the array?

Comment: Speed is quite similar. You may test the performance using the timeit magic function in ipython. Define a function you want to test, e.g., ``def unpack(): return [ col for cols in zip( *dfcolumns_list ) for col in cols ]`` and test the speed (in ipython) with ``%timeit unpack`` .

Comment: Thanks! Code optimization is not really a matter for this program, but I want to learn to program properly so I'm better knowing.